# Which are the Registry keys for installed programs in Windows?

Tags: windows, registry

I would like to know where installed programs store their registry keys, so that:
i.e. "Programs and Features" knows what programmes are installed.

It seems, to me, that there are more than one single location.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found out until now are the following locations:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall